# Gitlab vs Registry in docker container behind proxy ERROR

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, gitlab, docker-registry

I'm trying to enable gitlab registry running in docker behing nginx proxy on centos lxd container :)

Nginx's configuration on centos

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name registry.site.name;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; 

  access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;
}

server{
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name registry.site.name;
  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.name/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.name/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;


  location /{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
  }
}
```

Gitlab.rb configuration

```
registry_external_url 'https://registry.site.name'
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
registry['enable'] = true
registry['registry_http_addr'] = "git.site.name:8085" # (it is the same as gitlab ip - 172.17.0.3:8085)
registry_nginx['enable'] = false
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    container_name: 'git'
    hostname: 'git.site.name'
    ports:
      - '22:22'
      - '8081:8081'
      - '8085:8085'
    volumes:
      - '/data/Projects/git/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/var/log/git:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/data/Projects/git/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    network_mode: bridge
```

Looks good. If i make a request to registry.site.name, i see it in gitlab/registry/current log. Registry page also opens good in the project.

But, i can't use CLI
Every time i'm trying to `docker login registry.site.name` it fails with

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.site.name/v2/: remote error: tls: protocol version not supported
```

And this request stopped before git docker container, my nginx proxy logs:

```
2020/08/05 10:42:21 [crit] 268168#0: *9 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 10.200.3.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

The same error is triggered if i try to check tls1.2 connection with
`curl -I -v -L --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 registry.site.name`

So maybe docker login uses tls 1.2 but i don't understand why it is not working, because i set it up in nginx config.

I also tried nginx configuraton from that question [gitlab docker registry with external nginx and omnibus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584834/gitlab-docker-registry-with-external-nginx-and-omnibus)

but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that nginx config FOR git.site.conf didn't contain TLSv1.2

So be sure that both config (git&registry) have tls 1.2 support